# upload directory using the webkitdirectory issue

Tags: multipartform-data

I have struggled for long hours on this issue.

I've tried to upload directory as below on the chrome browser.
1. click the button named with 'Browse...'.
2. select a directory named with 'a'.
3. at this point, the directory hierarchy is ignored.

the directory has a structure as below.
ex) d:/test/a/b/c/1.txt

I want to keep directory structure as 'a/b/c'.

anyone else to know the resolution?

```
<f:form method="post" action="uploadFiles" name="uploadFiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   Resource Id : <input type="text" name="resourceId" placeholder="ex) test or test_op"/><br/>
                   <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="" webkitdirectory="" jsonware="true"/>
                   <f:submit value="submit" />
               </f:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am struggling for the same cause. This code really makes it happen but theres a bug or something with the transfering of the files/folder, out of 25 only 20 gets send, But anyway it may help you. 
http://sapphion.com/2012/06/keep-directory-structure-when-uploading/
Let me know if you come up with something,